# Validate domain name in view model

Tags: c#, validation, dns

I have a form with a domain name field, I want to have domain name validation in the view model. The method at the moment is just checking they have filled the text area in, but wanted to check that it was a valid domain.

```
    {

        [RequiredField]
        public string DomainName { get; set; }

        public void Validate(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DomainName))
            {
                modelState.AddModelError("", LocalisationHandler.GetText(SystemComponent.TheSystem, "AuditingCompanyManagement_AuditingDomainNameRequiredValidationMessage"));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Define: valid domain. The easiest and probably safest, though least 'sure' is does it match domain.TLD

Comment: @AustinTFrench Agreed, but even that won't be enough. `example.co.uk` is a valid domain, because `co.uk` is a valid suffix, and `.UK` is the TLD.

Comment: Why do you want to do this validation and specifically why do you want/need to do it at the moment the form is entered? This may need various asynchronous calls in the back, like DNS ones, so if the validation can be separated from the form submission it is better, otherwise you risk blocking all your UI. You need to give more details on your constraints space.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek absolutely. Although I consider those TLD as well. I supposed ccTLD would be the more correct abbreviation.

Comment: @AustinTFrench The whole area is far more complicated in fact, wouldn't fit a comment or even this question at all. In the past for example with `.NAME` you could register only `firstname.lastname.NAME`.  The TLD is still `NAME`, but `lastname.NAME` would not be "valid" in the sense you couldn't register it at all, you needed to register the subdomain. This restriction has been changed now but it just shows the structure can be complicated. Like in `.US` in the past which was 4th or 5th level only. (again this was relaxed over the year).